# Arduino Leonardo serial communication

Tags: serial-port, arduino, usb

The USB port on my Arduino Leonardo broke off and I don't have a USB-to-serial adapter. Is it possible to wire a USB cable to the TX, RX, Vin, and GND pins so that I can use serial communication between it and my computer?

(It already has my sketch on it.)

Comment: USB is a bus, and has a bus protocol.  It is far more complex than a simple communications link like RS232.  So "no".

Comment: But the atmega32u4 has built in usb to serial conversion, so I assumed it would still work?

Comment: If the *"USB port on my Arduino Leonardo"* is a *device* port, and you installed the ACM driver on the PC, then a host-to-device connection is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can solder a USB cable (just cut the type B end off of a standard A-B cable) onto the exposed pads where the port used to be.

Unlike other Arduinos, the Leonardo does not have a built-in USB-to-serial converter the drives the USB port. The microcontroller firmware provides USB device-mode support directly. It also has serial I/O pins.